# Fire macro only once in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I have a macro which remembers a previous clicked ID for the next event, which is quite handy and it works fine. When I use the macro in a firing rule, where the firing rule is not used, it also works good. However, when I use the firing rule for a Tag, it get's calculated twice and so it forget the previous clicked ID and only returns the current clicked ID. Is there a way to let this Macro only be calculated once?

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie in your macro

```
document.cookie="hasexecuted=true";
```

Create a second macro of the cookie type and name it e.g. "hasexecuted". Use it to check for the presence of the cookie. The cookie macro will be filled in with a value before any custom javascript values, so you can use it's return value in your custom macro function:

```
function() {
if({{hasexecuted == true}}) { return; }
....
}
```

Google Tag Manager does not have any memory all by itself so you need to implement your own storage and for such a simple thing a cookie might be easiest (if course this means a wee bit more overhead since cookie data is send to the server, so you might want to use localstorage or something like it).

Comment: You could use localStorage or sessionStorage too.

Comment: Is it true that localStorage does not work, when I submit a aspnet form? I noticed that when I am in Debug Mode in GTM, it does remember the previous ID. And when I publish the container and send an aspnet form, it does not remember the previous ID of the submit button.